# Dashed lines in dope sheet, can't edit keyframes

Tags: animation, graph-editor, dopesheet

[image: Image of dope sheet]

I have an animation of an object (just locRotScale keyframes) that I was editing. I don't know if I pressed a key or what but my keyframes in the graph editor turned from selectable with solid lines to these dashed lines. I can't even delete them as when I right click on them the options are all greyed out. Is there any way to delete these or get them back to being editable?

Comment: This is actually the Graph Editor, not the Dope Sheet. christopheS's answer helped me too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you pressed tab wich lock the curve, press tab again

Comment: Thank you so much! Did not expect it to be so simple.